# Boost Exception handling

Tags: c++, debugging, boost, exception

I am considering using boost exception handling in my application. The main benefit from adopting boost exception handling is I can add metadata to the exceptions. This can ease debugging and allow more information to be propagated upwards as the exception stack is unwound. However I am not clear with the performance implications of this. How is boost exception handling implemented - Are the error_info objects stored in a map internally (with log(n) insertion at every insertion)! Any known cons of boost exception handling!

Comment: I would *guess* that any map insertion or other processing for the metadata that is possibly done will pale in comparison to the overhead of actually (re)throwing the C++ exception.

Comment: Exceptions should be exceptional (sorry for the tautology). Exception handling overhead should be considered only for the case when no exception occurs. Overhead of handling of a *thrown* exception should be irrelevant. If it's not the case, it's a sign of a design error.

Comment: @atzz: it is relevant, if I throw an exception I what it to be caught today, not tomorrow.

Comment: @ybungalobill - let's not argue for the sake of arguing. If you don't agree with my comment, please re-phrase yours in a form that allows constructive discussion.

Comment: @atzz: I claim that exceptions should be as efficient as possible as long they don't affect the non-exceptional code.

Comment: @ybungalobill - I'm assuming that software engineers are sane people and won't add deliberate pessimizations. Having this out of the way, remember that nothing is free. Optimization generally costs a lot in development and much more in maintenance. I think that exception handling is not the place to focus on performance; it's better kept concise and readable. Exceptions happen rarely, so you'd gain nothing in overall performance. OTOH, exception handling code comes into focus during product evolution and maintenance quite frequently, so readability pays here.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, as far as I saw, the following load accompanies
for operator<<.

- `new error_info` for initializing of
  `shared_ptr< error_info >`
- `new
  exception_detail::error_info_container_impl`
  for initializing of `intrusive_ptr<
  exception_detail::error_info_container>`
- `operator[]` for inserting these in
  `std::map< typeinfo,
  shared_ptr<error_info_base const> >`

I cannot say whether these load matter in your situation.
If you are concerned, it'd be better to measure the load in the actual
environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error infos are stored in a map. The cost of inserting error_info is negligible both in terms of speed (throwing and stack unwinding is probably lot slower) and space (all memory is reclaimed at the end of the catch, typically soon after all the other memory freed as the stack unwinds.)